# Offline context with Wagtail Page data (Django-Compressor)

Tags: django, wagtail, django-compressor

I've got Wagtail set up with Django-Compressor (`COMPRESS OFFLINE = True`) which all works except for one template.

This template uses the Disqus plugin which requires:

1. An absolute page url
2. A unique page identifier

In my template I have included the following:

```
{% compress js inline %}
// My JS Code
this.page.url = "{{ page.full_url }}";
this.page.identifier = {{ page.id }};
{% endcompress %
```

So when accessing the page I get the error `You have offline compression enabled but key "ARANDOMKEYGOESHERE" is missing from offline manifest.` As per the Django-Compressor docs:

> If you use any variables inside the `{% compress %}` blocks, make sure to list all values you require in `COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT`

How would I go about adding the `Page` instance to the context in my settings? I thought of something like (pseudo-code):

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = { 'page': request.get('page') }
```

Comment: Offline compression cannot possibly work in this situation, because it requires the JS files to be generated in advance - the `./manage.py compress` command would have to know every possible URL.

Comment: @gasman ah I see the issue now. Can you think of any ways around this, short of updating the context every time a new page with that template is created? Thanks

Comment: What's the motivation for running these two lines through `{% compress %}` anyway? I'd just put them in a plain `<script>` tag.

Comment: @gasman Well, damn, that solution is so ingeniously simple that I love it but also feel stupid for not thinking of it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @gasman So is it okay to use multiple times `{% compress %}`  tag in Django templates for multiple <script> tags if I declare all the variables first and then use  `{% compress %}`  multiple times for other js code. and after that do I require these `COMPRESS OFFLINE = True` settings, bcoz now all js code is independent from a dynamic variable?